# Which condition condones best to good practice?

Tags: c++

I am refactoring old code, thus trying to follow best practices while I do so.

My real case resembles the below example:

```
#define FOO 0x0001

long bar = 0;
```

Should I test like this:

```
if(bar & FOO)
```

Or like this:

```
if(bar == FOO)
```

After seeing the comments, I am editing in order to clear things out:

`bar` can be any valid `long` number. I am trying to test if `bar` is equal to `FOO`, not if flag `FOO` is set.

One more time, I am trying to follow best practices for this, hence the question.

To me, it seems there is no significant difference, but wanted to check with experts.

I am restricted to Windows, using VS 2019, if more info is needed, feel free to ask.

Thank you.

Comment: Can `bar` ever be any value other than 0 or 1? If not, then it doesn't matter which way you go. But if it can, then the approach you use makes a bigger difference. What is `bar`'s purpose?

Comment: The two tests are different ! The first one is equivalent to `if (bar%2 == 1)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: yes, `bar` can be any value. Regarding the purpose, I am new employee in the company that still learns the system. I can not yet reliably answer that question. All I can say is that it does change its value during program execution, and it does not have to be `1` or `0` it can be `400` for example.

Comment: Binary and (`&`) and comparison for equality (`==`) do different things, use whatever is logically correct. For example `1 & 3 => 1 => true` while `1 == 3 => false` . If you aim for good practice you should replace the macro with a `constexpr` or `const` variable.

Comment: The best practice is to write what you mean. Do you mean "are there any bits that are set in both `bar` and `FOO`", or do you mean "is `bar` exactly the same as `FOO`"?

Comment: @molbdnilo: The latter I think (I am new employee, just came in contact with the code).

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Then I would recommend that you ask your coworkers instead of random strangers on the internet.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Of course I will, but we work in different time zones, so I wanted to do something on my own (besides going through the code) while I wait for them.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff I see. Working across time zones can be frustrating even when you're not new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two convey different meanings. `x==y` means "*Check that `x` is exactly equal to `y`*", `x&y` means "*check if any of bits in `y` are set in `x`*".

The result is the same, but what if `FOO` will change? If I come and 5 years in change `FOO` to 3, is `x=1` still valid?

Also, in modern C++ you should avoid macros. `constexpr unsigned FOO = 1;` is type safe.

Answer (score 1):

It strongly depends on what you are trying to test. If `bar` is set of flags and you want to check if one of flags is set - namely `FOO` - then go with:

```
if (bar & FOO) ;
```

If you want to check if only `FOO` is set then go on with:

```
if (bar == FOO) ;
```

So the main gist is - reveal your intentions within the code.

Additionaly I would reconsider using `long` as type for flag set. There is `std::bitset` type which is IMO great semantically to show that you are dealing with flags set.

Comment: Thank you for answering, since I am new employee, I can not offer much info. However, it seems that your observation #2 is the case.

Comment: If you find any of the answers helpful consider upvoting/accepting them, comments are second class citizens here ;)

Comment: Of course,I just need a little time to check/test the code/talk to the senior colleagues (since I am new) in order to be certain.

Answer (score 1):

If you really care about best practices of using modern c++, don't use macros at the first place. You can replace it with a `const` or `constexpr`.

Once you use a  `const` or `constexpr` the expression becomes simple.

```
if(something_const == something_non_const)
```

You can always refer http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html for the core cpp guidelines.